# For the regex gurus, split by -> and avoiding bracket/quotes contents

Tags: javascript, regex

### Given string:

> funny -> **A_gre$" [ "at** -> looks -> **great/*54[ [funny " -> [ " -> [great -> yolo] -> looks]][great]** -> a2afg34423*/- -> **yolo" -> [ "**

### Split to Array:

1. funny
2. A_gre$' [ 'at
3. looks
4. great/*54[ [funny ' -> [ ' -> [great -> yolo] -> looks]][great]
5. a2afg34423*/-
6. yolo' -> [ '

### A Regex Solution??!?

Basically, if there are quotes around the bracket(s), avoid the brackets' function as open/close delimiters otherwise make sure the text between the open bracket and close bracket are voided. How would i achieve this using Regex?

### **My Parser Solution** [Test](http://jsfiddle.net/rJzLJ/2/)

```
var s = "funny -> A_gre$' [ 'at -> looks -> great/\*54[ [funny ' -> [ ' ->"
        + "[great -> yolo] -> looks]][great] -> a2afg34423*/- -> yolo' -> [ '",
    p = 0,
    z = [0],
    q = 0,
    x = s.split('');

//Looking for \" not \'
for(var i = 0; i< x.length; i++){
   var b = x[i],
       c = x[i + 1],
       q = b == "'" ? ++q : q,
       p =  !(q % 2) ? b == '[' ? ++p : b == ']' ? --p : p : p;

   if(b == '-' && c == '>' && !p && !(q % 2))
       z.push(i + 2);
   if(i == x.length - 1){
       z.push(x.length); x = [];
       for(var u = 0; u < z.length; u++)
         z[u + 1] !== undefined ?
              x.push(s.substring(z[u], z[u + 2] !== undefined ?
                      z[u + 1]-2 : z[u + 1]).trim()) : 0;
    }
}

console.log(x)
```

### Ouput:

```
->>> [
      "funny", 
      "A_gre$' [ 'at", 
      "looks", 
      "great/*54[ [funny ' -> [ ' -> [great -> yolo] -> looks]][great]", 
      "a2afg34423*/-", 
      "yolo' -> [ '"
     ]
```

Comment: No. For nested brackets, you cannot use regex. Use a simple parser instead.

Comment: @M42: My solution was a parser, but that just seemed messy for this simple problem.

Comment: Why is it split at `->` after `A_gre$' [ 'at`? What about the opening `[`?

Comment: basically, if there are quotes around the bracket(s), avoid the bracket(s) as open/close otherwise make sure the text between the open bracket and close bracket are voided.

Comment: @bluejamesbond OK, you changed the question, and I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
([^\s\[\"]*\[[^\]]+\])\S*|([^\s\[\"]*\"[^\"]+\")\S*|(\w\S*)
```

Use [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) to see what it matches. It consists of three parts. The description for one of them is as follows:

```
([^\s\[\"]*\[[^\]]+\])\S*
```

expressions that reads non-space, non-quote, and non-bracket characters, until it reaches an open bracket, then reads the bracket contents until it reaches the closing bracket, then reads any non-space characters occurring after it. This is more detailed description of bracket matching part:

```
\[         : opening bracket character
[          : regex syntax for starting a set definition
   ^       : It's a negative set, i.e., set of characters which are NOT:
   \]      : closing bracket character
]+         : regex syntax for ending a set definition and the + operator for matching 1 or more occurrences
\]         : closing bracket character
```

Another section handles the quotes, and another section matches words without bracket and quotes.

The following code shows how to see the matches, and how to extract them:

var input = 'funny -> A_gre$" [ "at -> looks -> great/*54[ [funny " -> [ " -> [great -> yolo] -> looks]][great] -> a2afg34423*/- -> yolo" -> [ "'

```
var regexp = /([^\s\[\"]*\[[^\]]+\])\S*|([^\s\[\"]*\"[^\"]+\")\S*|(\w\S*)/g;

var result = input.match(regexp)
console.log("Array of matches are:");
console.log(result);

var results = regexp.exec(input);
while(results != null) {
    console.log("index: " + results.index + " found: " + results[0]);
    results = regexp.exec(input);
}
```

This can be seen live here: http://jsfiddle.net/LXqch/1/

Comment: I got the output: `'funny -> great -> looks -> great/*54[ funny -> great -> looks] -> 234423*/-'.split('(\S*\[[^\]]+\])|(\w\S*)')`
**===>** `["funny -> great -> looks -> great/*54[ funny -> great -> looks] -> 234423*/-"]` so, I am not sure what is going on here. It is not spliting into the array.

Comment: @bluejamesbond Use `.split(/(\S*\[[^\]]+\])|(\w\S*)/)` instead.

Comment: I get the output: `["", "funny->great->looks->great/*54[funny->great->looks]", undefined, "->", undefined, "234423*/-", ""]` which is not right for somebody

Comment: @bluejamesbond That's because of the `split` function. Use the `match` function to see what is matched: http://jsfiddle.net/bUpMJ/

Comment: I am confused how the first part of the OR and the second part of the OR work together. Can you please explain? PS. Need  I say, it looks superb.

Comment: Small problem...index: 35 + index 84 should be together.

Comment: @bluejamesbond that's actually a big problem. Matching nested brackets is not a regular language any more, and you can't use regular expressions for that. You have to implement a tiny customised parser for that.

Comment: I am not too good with this, but can't lookahead and lookbehind to solve this? I am saying this from the logical meaning of the terminologies. For instance, lookbehind to count the number of open brackets not inside quotes...Is this possible?